# Accidentally deleted Macintosh HD volumes rather than erasing!

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, recovery

I have accidentally erased the entire drive including the volumes rather than just erasing the contents when doing a clean install of Monterey.

Now I cannot run the Monterey OS installer from recovery mode because there is no firmware volume available. I have tried online recovery and with a USB. Also tried restoring from Time Machine.

Is there a way to restore the standard Macintosh HD and Macintosh HD - Data partitions from terminal in recovery mode? Or is there an easier way?
Thanks!

[image: diskutil screenshot]
[image: Disk Utility Screenshot]

Comment: Disk Utility does not show any internal disks in your machine. That's not good. Have you tried internet recovery without USB installer?

Comment: It crashes just before the end of the install - I think something to do with a missing firmware partition? I suspect the issue is something to do with partitioning the internal drive as APFS and the earliest available OS is Sierra, which does not support APFS. I'm working on booting to an external Sierra drive and then hoping I can repair the internal drive from there... Watch this space! Thanks for your help!

Comment: What model/year is  your Mac? I ask because Sierra only runs on Intel Macs  and Intel Macs do not have a firmware partition. Perhaps you mean an EFI partition? Either way, @Ihf is correct. The Disk Utility should show all internal drives regardless of partitioning or formatting.

Comment: It’s a 2016 MacBook Pro (i7). I think the disk partitioning must be corrupt - I can mount it as an external drive, but cannot mount any volumes or repair.

Comment: Either your internal drive has completely failed or your internal drive has been removed. Your Mac does not have a firmware partition on any internal or external drive. You are asking about something that never existed. Does your Mac have a Touch Bar?

Comment: The reference to a firmware partition came from trying to install Mac OS to an external drive - the drive was unavailable to install to and that was the reason given. I have now managed to boot up from an external drive - I thought I would be able to repair the disk form there, but alas, still not showing in diskutil. When I mounted the internal drive in target disk mode I could see the EFI partition, but again, could not run first aid on the disk or any of the volumes.

Comment: David: You might want to refer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/454439/macos-hdd-not-listed-anymore), which is similar to yours.

Comment: Thanks David. It does seem like an similar issue doesn’t it. And yes, it does have a touchbar.